# unable to import WriteToPubSub in python 2.7 with google-cloud-pubsub-0.37.2

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to utilize writing to pubsbub after reading from csv and writing few transforms, however, once i got to the point where i need to start working with pubsub, I am unable to import.
here is what I am importing:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import apache_beam as beam
from datetime import datetime
from beam_utils.sources import CsvFileSource
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import PubsubMessage
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import ReadStringsFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteStringsToPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteToPubSub
#from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteToPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import _PubSubSource
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
```

So far I figured only WriteToPubSub and WriteToPubSub are failing.

Fail looks like this:

> ```
> from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteToPubSub
>   ImportError: cannot import name WriteToPubSub
> ```

i see module is installed :

```
py -2 -m pip show google-cloud-pubsub
Name: google-cloud-pubsub
Version: 0.26.0
Summary: Python Client for Google Cloud Pub/Sub
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: jjg+google-cloud-python@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: d:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires: gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1, google-cloud-core, grpcio
Required-by:
```

upgraded the module:

```
Installing collected packages: google-cloud-pubsub
  Found existing installation: google-cloud-pubsub 0.26.0
    Uninstalling google-cloud-pubsub-0.26.0:
      Successfully uninstalled google-cloud-pubsub-0.26.0
Successfully installed google-cloud-pubsub-0.37.2
```

still the same issue

Would really love to understand what am I doing wrong with this? Wrong version?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are missing `proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4`.
As you are using GCP pubsub, use `pip install --upgrade apache-beam[gcp]` to install Apache Beam and all the required dependencies.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#get-the-apache-beam-sdk

Answer (score 0):

[WriteToPubSub](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.html#WriteToPubSub) belongs to `apache_beam`. Thus, check your `pip freeze` installation and look up for your apache beam version. For instance: `apache-beam==2.11.0`. If not, try installing `pip install apache-beam[gcp]` as it'll include the dependencies required to use features like the Google Cloud Dataflow runner. For more information, you could check this [link](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/#download-and-install).

Hope it helps.